# How to get reproducible Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder output in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, cryptography, pbkdf2

When running the `encode` method of a spring security Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder instance multiple times, the method returns different results for the same inputs. The snippet

```
String salt = "salt";
int iterations = 100000;
int hashWidth = 128;
    
String clearTextPassword = "secret_password";
    
Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder pbkdf2PasswordEncoder = new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder(salt, iterations, hashWidth);
String derivedKey = pbkdf2PasswordEncoder.encode(clearTextPassword);
System.out.println("derivedKey: " + derivedKey);
    
String derivedKey2 = pbkdf2PasswordEncoder.encode(clearTextPassword);
System.out.println("derivedKey2: " + derivedKey2);
```

results in a output like

```
derivedKey: b6eb7098ee52cbc4c99c4316be0343873575ed4fa4445144
derivedKey2: 2bef620cc0392f9a5064c0d07d182ca826b6c2b83ac648dc
```

The expected output would be the same values for both derivations. In addition, when running the application another time, the outputs would be different again. The different output behavior also appears for two different Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder  instances with same inputs. The `encoding` method behaves more like a random number generator. Spring boot version used is 2.6.1, spring-security-core version is 5.6.0 .

Is there any obvious setting that I am missing? The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.6.0/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder.html) does not give additional hints. Is there a conceptual error in the spring boot project set up?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any obvious setting that I am missing?

Yes. The documentation you linked to is fairly clear, I guess you missed it. That string you pass to the `Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder` constructor **is not a salt!**

The encoder generates a salt for you, and generates a salt every time you ask it to encode something, **which is how you're supposed to do this stuff**<sup>1</sup>. (The returned string contains both this randomly generated salt as well as the result of applying the encoding, in a single string). Because a new salt is made every time you call `.encode`, the `.encode` call returns a different value every time you call it, even if you call it with the same inputs.

The string you pass in is merely 'another secret' - which can sometimes be useful (for example, if you can store this secret in a secure enclave, or it is sent by another system / entered upon boot and never stored on disk, then if somebody runs off with your server they can't check passwords. PBKDF means that if they *did* have the secret the checking will be very slow, but if they don't, they can't even start).

This seems like a solid plan - otherwise people start doing silly things. Such as using the string `"salt"` as the salt for all encodes :)

The real problem is:

> The expected output would be the same values for both derivations

No. Your expectation is broken. Whatever code you are writing that made this assumption needs to be tossed. For example, this is how you are intended to use the encoder:

- When a user creates a new password, you use `.encode` and store what this method returns in a database.
- When a user logs in, you take what they typed, and you take the string from your database (the one `.encode` sent you) and call `.matches`.

It sounds like you want to again run `.encode` and see if it matches. Not how you're supposed to use this code.

---

### Footnote1: The why

You also need to review your security policies. The idea you have in your head of how this stuff works is thoroughly broken. Imagine it worked like you wanted, and there is a single salt used for all password encodes. Then if you hand me a dump of your database, I can trivially crack about 5% of all accounts within about 10 minutes!!

How? Well, I sort all hashed strings and then count occurrences. There will be a bunch of duplicate strings inside. I can then take all users whose passhash is in this top 10 of most common hashes and then log in as them. Because their password is `iloveyou`, `welcome123`, `princess`, `dragon`, `12345678`, `alexsawesomeservice!`, etcetera - the usual crowd of extremely oft-used passwords. How do I know that's their password? Because their password is the same as that of many other users on your system.

Furthermore, if none of the common passwords work, I can tell that likely these are really different accounts from the same user.

These are all things that I definitely should not be able to derive from the raw data. The solution is, naturally, to have a unique salt for everything, and then store the salt in the DB along with the hash value so that one can 'reconstruct' when a user tries to log in. These tools try to make your life easy by doing the work for you. This is a good idea, because errors in security implementations (such as forgetting to salt, or using the same salt for all users) **are not (easily) unit testable**, so a well meaning developer writes code, it seems to work, a casual glance at the password hashes seem to indicate "it is working" (the hashes seem random enough to the naked eye), and then it gets deployed, security issue and all.

Comment: Thanks, that sheds some light. I mistook the `secret` parameter as the `salt` parameter. So spring boot improves the security by auto salting 'under the hood'. Spring boot's usage focuses on authentication rather than key derivation, wich I was expecting for PBKDF2, too.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, how does matches() even work if the hash changes each time it is called? for instance, if you were to create your own version of method matches, i imagine that you would simply hash the rawPassword and compare it to the other argument. but if each invocation of encode produces a different value, then this cannot be correct.

Comment: The string you store in the database (the result of the `.encode(newPasswordJustChosenByUser)`) is a combination of the salt and the result of HASH(salt + pass), where the salt is randomly rolled up by the `.encode` function. The `.matches(passwordJustEnteredByTheUserLoggingIn, thingieIStoredInTheDbThatEncodeProduced)` can then do the work, as it can break that string back down into the salt and the HASH(salt+pass). Thus, it takes the salt, appends the password to it, hashes that, checks if it is identical. If yes, that was the right password. If no, it was not.